# First image on jQuery slider is out of place

Tags: jquery, css

I'm working on a jQuery slider. There are two images so far, and the first one is positioned incorrectly.

Here's the url that I'm working from: http://www.ayrturfandtrac.org/

It's on the bottom left side of the page.

I'd like to have the first image in the same place as the second image (centered between the buttons).

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="fader">
<img src="http://www.ayrturfandtrac.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/usedListing.png" class="usedListingImage">
<img src="http://www.ayrturfandtrac.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/kubotaB2320.png" class="usedListingImage">
</div>

<div id="next">
<img id="nextListing" class="nextListing" src="http://www.ayrturfandtrac.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/nextListingArrow.png" onmouseover="this.src='http://www.ayrturfandtrac.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/nextListingHover.png'" onmouseout="this.src='http://www.ayrturfandtrac.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/nextListingArrow.png'">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery (function() {
    $('#fader img:not(:first)').hide();

    $('#fader img').each(function() {
        var img = $(this);
        $('<img>').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).load(function() {
            img.css('margin-left', -this.width / 2 + 'px');
        });
    });

    var pause = false;

    function fadeNext() {
        $('#fader img').first().fadeOut().appendTo($('#fader'));
        $('#fader img').first().fadeIn();
    }

    function fadePrev() {
        $('#fader img').first().fadeOut();
        $('#fader img').last().prependTo($('#fader')).fadeIn();
    }

    $('#fader, #next').click(function() {
        fadeNext();
    });

    $('#prev').click(function() {
        fadePrev();
    });

    $('#fader, .button').hover(function() {
        pause = true;
    },function() {
        pause = false;
    });

    function doRotate() {
        if(!pause) {
            fadeNext();
        }    
    }

    var rotate = setInterval(doRotate, 5000);

});

</script>
```

Comment: include your CSS as wel please, for this slider

Comment: .nextListing {width:5%;float:right; margin:6% 5% 5% 5%;padding-right:5%;} .prevListing {width:5%;float:left; margin:7% 5% 5% 5%; } .used {float:left; width:50%;} .usedListingImage {width:65%;float:left; display:block; margin:-1% auto 0 auto;} #fader {display:block; margin-left:50%; width:95%}

Comment: redesign full gallery structure, or use something inbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the margin left of the images based on their widths:

```
$('<img>').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).load(function() {
    img.css('margin-left', -this.width / 2 + 'px');
});
```

However one of the image's ORIGINAL width is a lot larger than the other one. You are just resizing the images in the browser (which is never a good idea) and so the javascript is getting the original non-resized value. You can either just hardcode the margin left value by setting it to a good value like -160px:

```
img.css('margin-left', -'160px');
```

or make sure the images are resized to the same width, or you could also set the images inside of divs and get the width of the div instead.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Problem solved. Ended up changing that margin value to 0 in the JS and then adjusting my CSS a little bit. Thanks again. Are you on twitter?

Comment: Now, I'm getting a weird flicker when the images switch. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: You should wait for your first image to fade out before fading in the next one, if not you get both of them on top of each other. fadeOut has a callback function that gets called when the function finishes. So use that to determine when to fade in the next image like so:

`$('#fader img').first().fadeOut('slow', function() { "fade in next image here" })`

Comment: so I'll have to change these two sections of JS? to what? ...

    function fadeNext() {
        $('#fader img').first().fadeOut().appendTo($('#fader'));
        $('#fader img').first().fadeIn();
    }

    function fadePrev() {
        $('#fader img').first().fadeOut();
        $('#fader img').last().prependTo($('#fader')).fadeIn();
    }

Comment: Honestly you should figure that one out on your own as it's the best way to learn but I'll help you out here:
`$('#fader img').first().fadeOut('slow', function() { $(this).appendTo($('#fader'); $('#fader img').first().fadeIn(); });`

You can figure out how to do it for fadePrev(). This is also untested.

Answer (score 0):

The element style on the first image is set to margin-left: -607px;  That is causing the image to be way over to the left.  You need to play around with that structure.  Maybe take the styling out of the HTML element and into a css file.  I changed it to -160px and it looked more centered.

Comment: There is no styling in the HTML element. Do you think it's this line in the JS? img.css('margin-left', -this.width / 2 + 'px');